# how to display the key to the tableview

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, key

how to display the key on tableview at the same time?
Here I can display the value. 
I want to show the key on cell.textLabel setText:@"A"

Please..

.
.
.

Here is my code 
ThankYou
Thankyou very much.
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://reserve.cdn-apple.com/AU/en_AU/reserve/iPhone/availability.json"]];

```
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

     NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

        _listarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        id list = [dic objectForKey:self.strStore];
        if ([list isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)list;

            NSArray *keys = [list allKeys];
            for (NSString *key in keys) {
                NSString *teamname = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:key];
                NSLog(@"",key);
                [_listarr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", teamname]];
            }


        } else {
            // Do some error handling
        }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //必须返回与数据容器一样的数量，否则会报数据越界错
    return [_listarr count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"thisCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"A"];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[_listarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}



@end
```

Comment: NSDictionary has keys and values, NSArray only has values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this code will give you what you required I think..

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
NSArray *array = [dic allKeys];
NSArray *temparray = [dic objectsForKeys:array notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDictionary's [`allKeysForObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeysForObject:) to look up keys that match an object. Objects are compared with `isEqual:` and should match for simple NSStrings.

If the array is too large, this may be slow, in which case you might create another array with the key values that you can index quickly.